# Export Mongodb subdocuments to CSV

Tags: mongodb, csv, pymongo

I am having problems exporting subdocuments that are stored in MongoDB to a .CSV.

My data: a mongo collection that contains a unique user ID and scores from personality quizzes.

I would like a CSV that has three columns: user_id, name, raw_score. To add a further layer of complexity, within the 'scales' subdocument some users will have more than two entries (some quizzes produced more than 2 personality scores).

An example of my data minus documents that I am not interested in:

```
    "assessment":{
    "user_id" : "5839b1a654842f35617ad100",
    "submissions" : {
    "results" : {
            "scales" : [
                {
                    "scale" : {
                        "name" : "Security",
                        "code" : "SEC",
                        "multiplier" : 1
                    },
                    "raw_score" : 2
                },
                {
                    "scale" : {
                        "name" : "Power",
                        "code" : "POW",
                        "multiplier" : -1
                    },
                    "raw_score" : 3
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using mongoexport but this produces a CSV that only has a user_id column.

```
rekuss$ mongoexport -d production_hoganx_app -c assessments --type=csv -o app_personality.csv -f user_id,results.scales.scale.name,results.scales.raw_score
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing '=' sign from type. You could try --type csv